# Django render_to_string fails silent -- cannot trap error?

Tags: python, django

This is another one that's just bugging me

The code below is run as a management command upon completion of a long running task

```
logger.debug('preparing email')

context = {
    'project': task.project,
    'site': Site.objects.get(pk=settings.SITE_ID),
    'task': task,
    'user': task.user,
}
subject = 'Custom Assay Design of #%s - "%s" has completed' % (
    project.pk, project.title)

logger.debug('email step 1')
try:
    content_txt = render_to_string(
        'analysis/email/analysis_complete.txt', context)
except:
    logger.debug('failed to render string')
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc()

logger.debug('email step 2')
```

it didn't start with that much debugging or the generic try/except but that's where it's at now

if I step through everything in shell it works perfectly

if I change content_txt AND content_html to a string variable then things work

as it is the output looks like

```
2014-06-12 10:03:24,831 primer_search_finished line:28   DEBUG    Callback made to process PrimerTask 237
2014-06-12 10:03:24,831 primer_search_finished line:30   DEBUG    Trying to get task 237
2014-06-12 10:03:24,878 primer_search_finished line:54   DEBUG    Task 237 for project 280:Test -- 2014-04-11 marked complete
2014-06-12 10:03:24,889 primer_search_finished line:60   DEBUG    preparing email
2014-06-12 10:03:24,897 primer_search_finished line:71   DEBUG    email step 1
```

every time it just breaks when trying to run render_to_string

python version -- 2.7.5
django version -- 1.5.6

any ideas?

Comment: Did you try `render_to_string('analysis/email/analysis_complete.txt', context_instance=context)`?

Comment: triewd both dictionary=context & context_instance=context (though that's looking for a request instance) -- no-go on both -- but happy to try any new ideas

Comment: Could you maybe add the stack trace that the code gives if you remove the try.

Comment: it behaves the same with or without the try (no ouput, just silent exit), part of what's throwing me off

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your base directory is not the same when you are running the script vs when you are running from the command line testing.

What I would suggest:

```
...
try:
    content_txt = render_to_string(
        '%s/analysis/email/analysis_complete.txt' % PROJECT_ROOT, context)
....
```

This will ensure that you are actually looking in the right place for the file.

You will have to define `PROJECT_ROOT` before this. (You could look at using the location relative to this file `__file__`.)

Comment: nice idea but unfortauntely a no-go, I used the project dir stored in settings and joined paths -- dumped absolute path to console with logger to verify -- same behavior....